# java application using selenium web driver jars files imported

Tags: java, selenium

**When I run the java application using selenium web driver jars files imported.I'm getting below errors in console 
Can any one give the solution for this?**

```
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"26.0","maxVersion":"47.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
    1461298595367   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1461298595367   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1461298595367   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1461298595369   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1461298595374   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
    1461298595376   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1461298595408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595477   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1461298595485   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1461298595487   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1461298595488   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1461298596837   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298596837   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
    1461298596837   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1461298596850   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1461298596851   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1461298596855   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1461298596928   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596928   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596929   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596937   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1461298596937   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1461298597024   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298597029   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298603744   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
    1461298603749   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1461298604019   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604019   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604019   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1461298604020   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1461298604021   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1461298604023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298604025   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
    1461298604031   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
        at mySecondProgram.SeleniumFirstProject.main(SeleniumFirstProject.java:13)
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
    false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"26.0","maxVersion":"47.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
    1461298595367   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1461298595367   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1461298595367   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1461298595369   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1461298595374   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
    1461298595376   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1461298595408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595477   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1461298595485   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1461298595487   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1461298595488   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1461298596837   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298596837   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
    1461298596837   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1461298596850   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1461298596851   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1461298596855   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1461298596928   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596928   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596929   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596937   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1461298596937   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1461298597024   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298597029   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298603744   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
    1461298603749   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1461298604019   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604019   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604019   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1461298604020   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1461298604021   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1461298604023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298604025   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
    1461298604031   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
    System info: host: 'DESKTOP-CH3D0C4', ip: '192.168.0.6', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
        at mySecondProgram.SeleniumFirstProject.main(SeleniumFirstProject.java:13)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
    false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"26.0","maxVersion":"47.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
    1461298595367   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1461298595367   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1461298595367   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
    1461298595369   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
    1461298595374   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
    1461298595376   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595392   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1461298595408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
    1461298595408   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595476   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1461298595477   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1461298595485   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1461298595486   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1461298595487   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1461298595488   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
    1461298596837   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298596837   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
    1461298596837   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1461298596850   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
    1461298596851   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
    1461298596855   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
    1461298596928   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596928   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596929   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298596937   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1461298596937   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
    1461298597024   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298597029   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
    1461298603744   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
    1461298603749   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 8.0.0.9103
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1461298604018   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1461298604019   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604019   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
    1461298604019   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1461298604020   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1461298604021   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1461298604023   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1461298604025   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
    1461298604031   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: is your firefox is opening but firefox showing blank page?

Comment: Yes, whenever I run the java application the firefox browser is opening and getting all those errors in the eclipse console.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems

1. Fire Fox Path is wrong to fix this re-check path to firefox.exe
   try this by specifying path of FF

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("path/to/your/firefox.exe")), profile);

2. Binaries used are not compatible with your Fire Fox version.

To fix this go to selenium site and make sure you have compatible version with you browser
[Selenium Change Log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG)

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because of new issue in latest browser of firefox.

Update your selenium jars. The new version of firefox(Or different browser) is not supporting old jars of selenium.

Download both Selenium Server (formerly the Selenium RC Server) Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings

Replace them with old jars you are using. Update your mozilla also so you can get the updated results

source :- http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

To overcome from this issue you also need to setPreference as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false` to firefox Profile and then pass it to driver object

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
```

Below code is working fine for me.

```
static WebDriver driver=null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

Hope it will help you :)